# How to access specific row by index

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've a table view controller in which I want to dynamically create a row (cell). How can I access row by index number in Swift? The following is what I did and now I'm stuck here.

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "teamStats", for: indexPath) as! TeamStatsTableViewCell                            

    return cell
}
```

This is my TableViewController code in which I want to check if the row is at a specific index number.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. The `indexPath` parameter tells you the row (and section).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method is a delegate method which will be called every time a cell is displayed on your `UITableView`. So if you want to do something with a cell in a particular index, you do the following. Please go through Apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource) and get a better understanding of what delegate methods are.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "teamStats", for: indexPath) as! TeamStatsTableViewCell                            
    if indexPath.row == requiredIndex {
         //Do something.
    }
    if indexPath.row == lastIndex { // you have the last index with you. replace this variable with that. 
        cell.firstlabel.text = ""
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: i use like this   if indexPath.row == 0{
            cell.firstLabel.text = label
            
        }but it does not change the text of the label rather it's remove the previous text from label but not update it with the new one.

Comment: Where did you set the previous label?

Comment: now it's work but now i want that whenever the program reach to last cell the label should hide how to achieve it.

Comment: You want only the last cell label to hide?

Comment: i only have one label that i'm repeating in all the cell dynamically but at last cell i want to hide it.

Comment: Then just check if it the last cell and set `cell.firstLabel.text = ""`

Comment: thanks, but i used cell.secondLabel.isHidden = true
this. which work for me. could you please tell me about what is the difference when we check the "constraint to margin"in the constraint window or if we don't mark it. because my app is not full responsive for all devices.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
if indexPath.row == 1{
        //Your code
}
```

You can check the section :

```
if indexPath.section == 1{

    }
```

It may helps to you.Thank you